# Pluralise object keys that contain arrays

Tags: javascript

I have been given an object storing information on keys. I need to change the keys that contain arrays to be plural, for example:

```
{
   name: 'Tom',
   job: ['writing katas', 'marking'],
   favouriteShop: [
     "Paul's Donkey University",
     "Shaq's Taxidermy Shack",
     "Sam's Pet Shop"
   ]
};
```

Should be:

```
{
    name: 'Tom',
    jobs: ['writing katas', 'marking'],
    favouriteShops: [
      "Paul's Donkey University",
      "Shaq's Taxidermy Shack",
      "Sam's Pet Shop"
    ]
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can't you just change how the original output gets generated? It seems overly complicated to mutate an output

Comment: Also changing keys appended with *s* might be easy and achievable, But converting to exact plurals might be tricky. Do you want exact plurals?

Answer (score 2):

```js
const data = {
   name: 'Tom',
   job: ['writing katas', 'marking'],
   favouriteShop: [
     "Paul's Donkey University",
     "Shaq's Taxidermy Shack",
     "Sam's Pet Shop"
   ]
};

const newData = {};

for(key in data){
  const newKey = Array.isArray(data[key]) && data[key].length > 1 ? `${key}s` : key;
  newData[newKey] = data[key];
}

console.log(newData)
```

You can do it like this. Verify if the Object value is an array for each key and see if there is more than 1 item in the array and rename the key, if not just go with the old key. You just need to create the a new object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `reduce`:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Tom',
  job: ['writing katas', 'marking'],
  favouriteShop: [
    "Paul's Donkey University",
    "Shaq's Taxidermy Shack",
    "Sam's Pet Shop"
  ]
};

const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
  if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
    acc[`${key}s`] = obj[key]
  } else {
    acc[key] = obj[key]
  }
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is quite expensive (to do a shallow copy of `acc` on every key), why not simply create the new keys on an object that you return over time?

Comment: this avoids mutating original object.

Comment: sure, but there is no need for all the shallow copies afterwards, the first acc is already a new object since you specify a seed for the reduce function

Comment: Ahh, now I got what you mean. I'll update the answer.